# Why JavaScript shows "undefined" alert in the 1st line of of r() in the below snippet?

Tags: scope, global-variables, local-variables

Why JavaScript shows "undefined" alert in the 1st line of of r() in the below snippet?

[image: Image contains HTML & JavaScript code]

Comment: please don't share image of your code.

Comment: share your code in this post

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the var from the b in the r function. You cant set a local variable with the same name as global.

```
function r() {
    alert(b);
    b = "another stuff";
    alert(b);
    alert(window.b);
}
```

Comment: *"You cant set a local variable with the same name as global."* How sure are you about that statement?

Answer (score 0):

Look this: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript), point 7. 
JavaScript always moves variable declarations (not initializations) to the top of the scope.